# Dyamically redirect user after session timeout based on original Authentication

Tags: java, session, spring-security

I want to redirect a user to different login pages when the session has timed out and I get a request. I'm using Spring Security and having trouble accomplishing this with the security filters. The problem is that filters such as  `org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter` happen after the session has already been destroyed (and I think cleaned up by the application container). I don't seem to have access to the original authentication object that was used to create the session so I can't determine where the user should go on timeout.  Is there a way to accomplish this cleanly? Would I need to resort to writing a `HttpSessionListener` and storing information about the type of session on session timeout so that on the next request I can take appropriate action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll-your-own solution:

Upon login, you can manually set a non-expiring second cookie (other than the session id cookie) in the user's browser and use its value to determine which page to redirect to when the user's session has expired.